# swf to image on the website?

Tags: html, flash, actionscript-3, image, hotlinking

i want to convert a swf to image on my website. a user makes some changes on the stage and if he press a button "get image link", the swf stage will be converted to an image and its image link will appear within a box. like imageshack.. so user can use it in forums as image. how can i do this? i even dont know it is about flash or html...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a good read of [Henry Jones - Using the AS3 Jpeg Encoder](http://henryjones.us/articles/using-the-as3-jpeg-encoder). He explains exactly what you need, plus some!

You basically what to use the [BitmapData](http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) class to convert you displayobject into image data. Then you can use [JPGEncoder](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/source/browse/trunk/src/com/adobe/images/) from [AS3 Core Lib](http://code.google.com/p/as3corelib/), to encode that data into a JPEG. Then with a bit of serverside code you can send that JPEG to that server.

Comment: When I tried to access the Henry Jones link (attempted on Tuesday, May 29, 2012), it was broken. Quick searching on Google did not reveal anything. If anyone knows the current link, please update it.